# The most efficient way to check if a certain number fits in a large set of ranges

Tags: algorithm, search

I have a situation (where performance is critical) to check if a customer account number fits in anyone of a set of valid number ranges(about a thousand of them). What would be the most efficient way to do that? How (and where)store the ranges, how search through them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using the [Segment Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) to do this.

> A segment tree for a set I of n intervals uses O(n log n) storage and can be built in O(n log n) time. Segment trees support searching for all the intervals that contain a query point in O(log n + k), k being the number of retrieved intervals or segments.[1]

So it's really efficient doing the range queries.

Comment: Thanks qiao. I went on to look it up on the internet and found a somewhat related structure - the interval tree. Which of the two do you think works better?

Comment: @MeshSolomon The space consumption of Interval Tree is O(n) whereas Segment Tree is O(nlogn). Also, Interval Tree allows insert and remove operations while a Segment Tree is static. It seems that Interval Tree is superior but I'm not totally sure.

Comment: Thanks a lot 4 ur help qiao. I'll try to look into both of them closely.